# Is there a simpler way to do this script?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm learning and trying to put together a little bit of jquery. Admittedly I'm finding it difficult to find a good basics guide, particularly, when adding multiple actions to one page.

I read somewhere that the document listener should only be used once. I believe I'm using it twice here, but not 100% sure how to bring it into one listener.

Also because I've been hacking bits of script together, I think I'm using parts of javascript and parts of jQuery. Is this correct?

A critique of the code below [which does work] and any advice on how best to approach learning jQuery would be most helpful. Thanks.

**Script 1 styles a group of 3 radio buttons depending on which one is clicked.**
**Script 2 appends new inputs to the bottom of a form.**

```
var stateNo = <?php echo $HighestPlayerID; ?> + 1; 

$(document).on('click', 'input', function () {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    if ($('input[name="' + name + '"]:eq(1)')[0].checked) {
        $('label[name="' + name + '"]:eq(1)').addClass('nostate');
        $('label[name="' + name + '"]').removeClass('selected');
    }
    else {
        $('label[name="' + name + '"]').removeClass('nostate selected');
        if ($('input[name="' + name + '"]:eq(0)')[0].checked) {
            $('label[name="' + name + '"]:eq(0)').addClass('selected');
        }
        else {
            $('label[name="' + name + '"]:eq(2)').addClass('selected');
        }
    }
});


$(document).on('click', 'button[name=btnbtn]', function () {
    var stateName = 'state[' + stateNo + ']';
    var newPlayerAppend = `` +
        `<tr><td>` + 
        `<input type="hidden" name="state['` + stateNo + `'][PlayerID]" value="` + stateNo + `" /></td>` + 
        `<td><input name="` + stateName + `[Name]" value="Name"></td>` + 
        `<td><input name="` + stateName + `[Team]" type="radio" value="A">` +
        `<td><input name="` + stateName + `[Team]" type="radio" value="">` +
        `<td><input name="` + stateName + `[Team]" type="radio" value="B">` +
        `</td></tr>`;
    $("tbody").append(newPlayerAppend);
    stateNo++;
});
```

**HTML for the 3 radio button inputs**

```
<td class="Choice">
<label name="state[1][Team]" class="teampick Astate ">A
<input name="state[1][Team]" type="radio" value="A" />
</label>
<label name="state[1][Team]" class="smallx nostate ">X
<input name="state[1][Team]" type="radio" value="" checked />
</label>
<label name="state[1][Team]" class="teampick Bstate">B
<input name="state[1][Team]" type="radio"  value="B" />
</label>
</td>
```

Comment: Firstly, `jQuery` is a `JavaScript` library. You can't separate the two. It's still `JavaScript`. Secondly, questions seeking *"critique"* on code have the tendency of creating sterile debates, revolving around particular ways of doing the same thing, using different methods. Instead, you should try to formulate specific questions, around specific tasks. You're stating your scripts don't work but you don't clarify what's the desired output and behavior. Please try to be more specific.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu thanks for this, appreciate you taking the time for your input, that is something I will keep in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the code can be written more concisely, or more the jQuery way, but first I want to highlight an issue with your current solution:

The following would generate invalid HTML, if it were not that browsers try to solve the inconsistency:

```
$("tbody").append(newPlayerAppend);
```

A `tbody` element cannot have `input` elements as direct children. If you really want the added content to be part of the table, you need to add a row and a cell, and put the new `input` elements in there.

Here is the code I would suggest, that does approximately the same as your code:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input', function () {
    $('label[name="' + $(this).attr('name') + '"]')
        .removeClass('nostate selected')
        .has(':checked')
        .addClass(function () {
            return $(this).is('.smallx') ? 'nostate' : 'selected';
        });
});

$(document).on('click', 'button[name=btnbtn]', function () {
    $('tbody').append($('<tr>').append($('<td>').append(
        $('<input>').attr({name: `state[${stateNo}][PlayerID]`, value: stateNo, type: 'hidden'}),
        $('<input>').attr({name: `state[${stateNo}][Name]`, value: 'Name'}),
        $('<input>').attr({name: `state[${stateNo}][Team]`, value: 'A', type: 'radio'})
    )));
    stateNo++;
});
```

There is no issue in having two handlers. They deal with different target elements, and even if they would deal with the same elements, it would still not be a real problem: the DOM is designed to deal with multiple event handlers.

Comment: I shorten the HTML down for the sake of the question, but naively deleted the rows and cell references too. I'll re-insert them shortly. For the first part where you included `.addClass(function () {.....` etc, searching tells me that what follows this is a short hand if statement. Is this part checking that `$(this)` object has the class `.smallx`? and by that logic could I could change this to the attribute name (if it was unique). Essentially would `$(this).is('state[unique]') work?

Comment: `$(this).is('')` often add filters and allows you to test the contents of an element or object. in this context it is label  which has the name already rendered so, `.$(this).is("[name='state[unique]']")  ? 'nostate' : 'selected';` would work.

Comment: Indeed, `addClass` callback function is called for the label that has the selected input, which is represented by `this`. The `is` method returns a boolean (`true` if the selected label has the `.smallx` class), and depending on that value, either `'nostate'` or `'selected'` is returned. jQuery uses that return value as the class name to add. You can replace the part between `return` and the `?` by any condition you find useful.

Comment: Thanks @trincot this proved very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1. There are 2 places you are using anonymous functions. If the code block moves to a named function, the entire code becomes more maintainable. It also helps better in debugging by telling you upfront which function name the error may lie in.
2. Once you have named functions you will realise that you really do have 2 event listeners for click. So there isn't much benefit of moving them in one listener (or one function you may be referring to). These both event listeners attach on document object and listen to a click event.
3. Class names are always better when hyphenated. `a-state` over `Astate`.
4. If it works it is correct code, for once you asked about correctness.

Comment: Thanks Priya, I'm going to look into each of these items and see if I can improve my script.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely fine to have multiple listeners but I usually prefer making everything under one roof. Consider making code as simple as possible which saves lot of time during maintenance.

you can use **$(function() {})** or **document.ready()**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function() {
     var thisa = $(this).parent();
     var name = $(this).attr("name");
     // Remove :selected class from the previous selected labels.
      $('label[name="' + name + '"]').removeClass('selected');
      // Add conditional class with tenary operator.
      thisa.parent().hasClass("smallx") ? thisa.addClass('nostate') : thisa.addClass('selected');
    });

    $('button[name=btnbtn]').click(function() {
         var stateName = 'state[' + stateNo + ']';
            // Add TR and TD before appending the row to tbody
            var newPlayerAppend = `<tr><td>` + 
                `<input type="hidden" name="state['` + stateNo + `'][PlayerID]" value="` + stateNo + `" />` + 
                `<input name="` + stateName + `[Name]" value="Name">` + 
                `<input name="` + stateName + `[Team]" type="radio" value="A"></td></tr>`;

            $("tbody").append(newPlayerAppend);
            stateNo++;
    });
 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for this, the 'putting everything under one roof element shows me how I can restructure parts in a different way - The way I was expecting I could.

Comment: I am glad it helped @denski.